# Issues with $event.stopPropagation on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Okay so I've been trying to work around this issue. I had previous help with getting to this point and I'm trying to solve an issue when you click and drag a selection under an expanded optgroup it collapses the optgroup. I've been trying to run jquery class events in the controller to prevent this from happening and unfortunately nothing is happening. I've even tried calling a function on click of an option that checks for the parent/ children but I think I'm missing something. for now here is the plnkr of what currently works: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/l9NNqkAZaBijR8OuDQhu?p=preview)

I was wondering if this is a known issue and if so is there a better way around this? This is the first time I've used stopPropagation so I'm most likely not using it right. The stopPropagation works for when you select an option individually or hold down ctrl/shift and select. If you click and drag pass the labels or pass the bottom of the options they don't collapse but if you click and drag and stop on an option is collapses.

Below are GIFs of what I'm trying to explain:

[image]

[When drag pass an the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDm57.jpg)

[image]

[When you drag to an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7GAR.jpg)

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  <select multiple class="box">
    <optgroup ng-click="value.expanded = !value.expanded" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" label="{{value.label}}">
      <option ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-if="value.expanded" ng-repeat="id in value.ids">{{id}}</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

the rest is in the plnkr

Comment: I forgot to include my actual question, just updated it

Comment: Could you create a animated gif of what happends? I cant get you.

Comment: [When you drag pass the options](http://imgur.com/a/vzpyp)

Comment: [When you drag to an option](http://imgur.com/a/Z5TNC)

Comment: Hopefully that can help haha, I tried to explain in words the best I could but a visually explanation usually works best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stupid behavior while the `optgroup` is the parent element and its the height of the child elements in DOM. So, once you moved the cursor while dragging and stop dragging the event `ng-click` is fired on the `optgroup` element aswell(because the cursor is upon it). I've made it work by adding a software switch as you can see in this [runnable plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gfDhMYHhrbyTWQzrUw5l?p=preview).

#### View

```
<select multiple class="box">
  <optgroup ng-click="clickOptGroup(key);" ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" label="{{value.label}}">
    <option ng-mousedown="mouseDown()" ng-mouseup="mouseUp()" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" ng-if="value.expanded" ng-repeat="id in value.ids">{{id}}</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var app = angular.module('test',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',function ($scope, $timeout) {

   var mouseDown = false;

    $scope.data = [{
        label: "My Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ], 
        expanded: true
    },{ 
        label: "My Other Label", ids: [ "one id", "another id" ], 
        expanded: false
    }];

    $scope.clickOptGroup = function (key) {
      console.log('in');
      if (!mouseDown) {
         $scope.data[key].expanded = ! $scope.data[key].expanded;
      }
    }

    $scope.mouseDown = function ($event) {
      console.log('mouseDown');
      mouseDown = true;
    }
    $scope.mouseUp = function ($event) {
      $timeout(function () {
         mouseDown = false;
      }, 50);
    }
});
```

Comment: wow... I seriously did not think of creating a duel mouseup/ mousedown event check at all on this.... impressive and glad to know that this is an ever going issue I really appreciate the quick response too

Comment: @DrMints glad to help ya.

Comment: I actually caught another bug hahaha, I noticed how when I click and drag pass the optgroup labels I can no longer expand/ collapse unless I re-select an option without dragging pass the label

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow.